# I am trying to get the addition value of using return function but not getting | Could you help to me what exactly I am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, return

I am trying to get the added value of using return function.

```js
var x, y;

function test(x, y) {
  x = prompt("Enter a number");
  y = prompt("enter another Number");
  return (x + y);

}
test();
```

Answer (score 2):

`.prompt()` returns a string. You need to convert that to a number with something like `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` etc:

```js
var x, y, result;

function test(x, y) {
  x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
  y = parseInt(prompt("enter another Number"));
  return (x + y);

}
console.log(test());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save `x` and `y` values to your predefined variables, just remove them as arguments from `test` function - then it will use your predefined ones:

```js
var x, y, result;

function test() {
  x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"), 10);
  y = parseInt(prompt("enter another Number"), 10);

  return x + y;
}

console.log(test(), x, y);
```

Also as @j08691 suggested, you should convert results of `prompt` to number first before making the sum.

Comment: Thank you so much I understood the Problem why I was having the issue because the prompt is taken by string value not the integer value. so that the output was not showing.

Comment: Here I did it.                                                                                           
var x,y;
function test(x,y) {
 x=Number(prompt("Enter a number"));
 y=Number(prompt("enter another Number"));
 return (x+y);
}
alert(test());